# How can i combine mouseover, mouseout and click. Without having .mouseout ruin .click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**Situation**
I have a div, when your mouse is over this div another appears. When you leave the div with your mouse it dissapears. But when you click it it has to stay even if you leave the div with your mouse.

**Question**
How can i make .click over rule .mouseout?

**Code**

```
$('.btn-morgen').mouseover(function() {
    $('#mapster_wrap_0 img').attr("src", '/media/ae/ae24c4cd276383e1474c6ebe93a127f3/950/kaartje.png');
    $('.gebied1').css("display","block");
    $('.gebied2').css("display","none");
});
$('.btn-singel').mouseover(function() {
    $('#mapster_wrap_0 img').attr("src", '/media/fe/feb86620fba224e28d5c7f4bf6307ece/950/kaartje.png');
    $('.gebied1').css("display","none");
    $('.gebied2').css("display","block");
});
$('#mapwrapper').mouseout(function () {
    $('#mapster_wrap_0 img').attr("src", '/media/c8/c88c72323acecefbab1ec173c5eb0b1a/950/kaartje.png');
    $('.gebied1').css("display", "none");
    $('.gebied2').css("display", "none");
});
$('#mapwrapper').mouseout(function () {
    $('#mapster_wrap_0 img').attr("src", '/media/c8/c88c72323acecefbab1ec173c5eb0b1a/950/kaartje.png');
    $('.gebied1').css("display", "none");
    $('.gebied2').css("display", "none");
});
$('.btn-morgen').click(function() {
    $('#mapster_wrap_0 img').attr("src", '/media/ae/ae24c4cd276383e1474c6ebe93a127f3/950/kaartje.png');
    $('.gebied1').css("display","block");
    $('.gebied2').css("display","none");
});
$('.btn-singel').click(function() {
    $('#mapster_wrap_0 img').attr("src", '/media/fe/feb86620fba224e28d5c7f4bf6307ece/950/kaartje.png');
    $('.gebied1').css("display","none");
    $('.gebied2').css("display","block");
    $('.btn-morgen').css("background-color","f4f0d3");
});
```

Comment: a hacky method could be something like a global boolean, in which you want to check the value in the mouseout event if it is false and set it on click to true.

Comment: please provide html and js code when ever possible, jsfiddle or snippet is even better, that way users can quickly get into the problem your facing, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a flag to save the state:

```
(function() {
    var clicked=false;
    $myDiv.click(function () {
        //logic to show other div
        clicked=!clicked;
    });
    $myDiv.mouseout(function() {
        if (!clicked) {
            //code to hide the div
        }
    });
})();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `css` for `mouseenter` and `mouseout` and add a click event to toggle state.

Note: `+` in css selector means next sibling. If its not next sibling, use `~` as this will check for all siblings

```js
$('.main').on("click", function(){
  $(this).siblings('.tile').removeClass('hide');
})
```

```css
.main{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid gray;
}
.main:hover ~ .hide.tile{
  display: block;
}
.tile{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
.hide{
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">main container</div>
<div >Dummy</div>
<div class="tile hide">tile</div>
```